# Train and test the model using 2 separate datasets

Tags: machine-learning, regression, machine-learning-model

I have a big data-set (14K subjects) and a small data-set (100 subjects). Both have same number and similar features (20). They are not overlapped.
I used the big data-set to train a regression model and validate it. Then I identified the most significant features in the big data-set.
Now I want to identify most significant features in the small data-set. 
My question is, should I train the model on the small or on the big data-set?
If I train the model on the big and then test on the small, this might results in high MAE which is reasonable, but I am afraid will not give me the right list of significant features.
If I train the model on the small data-set and then test on the same data-set, this might results in low MAE, but this might provide the right list of significant features.
What do you think?

Comment: Aren't both datasets the same type of data? If your small dataset has a different set of features, how are you planning to use your model on it?

Comment: @ncasas. They have same set of features.

Comment: And how is the data you plan to use your model on when it's ready? Is it more similar to the small dataset? Why did you decide to you have 2 datasets in the begining?

Comment: The first data is for healthy people. The second data for patients people. Both have same  features. I want to know how to identify the significant features in patients group. Should I train the model on healthy or on patinas ? @ncasas

Comment: You should train the model on data that is similar to the data that- you will use it with in production.

Comment: thanks so much @ncasas

Comment: I have added the previous comment as an answer so that it can be upvoted and marked as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the idea is that the model should be trained on data that is similar to the one you will use in production. Otherwise, you would be training your model to be good at something other than what you would be evaluating it on.